# How do I set download directory for Google Chrome using Selenium (NodeJS)?

Tags: node.js, selenium, automated-tests

I have a test in NodeJS that downloads a file from a website using Google Chrome on the cloud (BrowserStack). I am trying to download the file to a directory in my project. I understand I have to set this via Chrome Options but no answers posted here to seem work.

Could someone please share an example how this is done using NodeJS? Below is one example I have tried that doesn't work.

```
module.exports.createChromeDriver = async function () {
    if (parameters.runOnCloud === true) {

        await filesDirectory.createAppDirIfRequired(paths.tempDir, paths.downloadDirName);

        let capabilities = {
            'name' : parameters.report,
            'browserName' : 'Chrome',
            'browser_version' : '79.0',
            'os' : 'OS X',
            'os_version' : 'Mojave',
            'resolution' : '1920x1080',
            'browserstack.user' : credentials.browserstack.user,
            'browserstack.key' : credentials.browserstack.key,
            'browserstack.local' : 'true',
            'browserstack.localIdentifier': parameters.bsLocalIdentifier,
            'browserstack.networkLogs' : 'false',
        }

        if (parameters.tests === "wallet-web") {
            capabilities['browserstack.networkLogs'] = 'true';
        }

        let options = new chrome.Options();
        const prefs = {'download.default_directory' : paths.downloadsDir};
        options.addArguments('prefs', prefs);
        options.merge(capabilities);

        let driver = await new Builder().
            usingServer('http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub').
            withCapabilities(capabilities).
            build();

        return driver;
    }
```

Comment: Please add how you have declared downloadsDir. What is your OS (WIndows, Linux)?

Comment: It just a folder path within the project. Mac OS Mojave.

Comment: You can have a mistake in the downloadsDir variable declaration. How do you set it? Are you sure it is not undefined? You have both paths.downloadDirName and paths.downloadsDir in this script.

Comment: That just creates the directory in the project if not there using the name.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake when set the capabilities. `capabilities` does not include `download` option, because `merge`(`options.merge(capabilities);`) operator means , merge `capabilities` in to `options`.

You only need change one line:

```
withCapabilities(capabilities).
```

to

```
withCapabilities(options.toCapabilities()).
```

If it not working, I think you have to change the `option` variable, like:

```
const options = new chrome.Options();
options.setUserPreferences({
  'download.default_directory': paths.downloadsDir,
  'download.prompt_for_download': false, // Maybe
});
options.merge(capabilities);
```

Update:

The final way, you can try use

```
capabilities['goog:chromeOptions'] = options;
```

instead of

```
options.merge(capabilities);
```

Comment: .toCapabilities() is not a function. If I use just options its still doesn't download to the directory.

Comment: WebDriverError: The property '#/' contains additional properties ["browserName", "goog:chromeOptions"] outside of the schema when none are allowed in chromeOptions